# Getting an IndexError: list index out of range in line no. = 19?

Tags: python-3.x, list

import csv

with open('C:/Users/dkarar/Desktop/Mapping project/RC_Mapping.csv', 'r') as file1:
    with open('C:/Users/dkarar/Desktop/Mapping project/Thinclient_mapping.csv', 'r') as file2:
        with open('C:/Users/dkarar/Desktop/Mapping project/output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            reader1 = csv.reader(file1)
            reader2 = csv.reader(file2)

```
        for row in reader1:
            if not row:
                continue

            for other_row in reader2:
                if not other_row:
                    continue

                # if we found a match, let's write it to the csv file with the id appended
                if row[1].lower() == other_row[1].lower():
                    new_row = other_row
                    new_row.append(row[0])
                    writer.writerow(new_row)
                    continue

            # reset file pointer to beginning of file
            file2.seek(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be getting at least one row where there is a single element. That's why when accessing `row[1]` you get an `IndexError`, there's only one element in the list `row`.